# The volume “Filesystem Root” has only 533.9 MB disk space remaining

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount

I have run into this problem two days ago. The OS warns me that root has limited disk space:

[image: warning screenshot]

So I would like to add more space to the root filesystem. These are the partitions I have:

[image: Here are the disk partitions]

### `sda9 : /home` `sda7 : /` `sda8 : swap`

I would like to reduce the size of `/dev/sda6` which is 70 GB in size,

1. How can I reduce the size of `/dev/sda6` and convert it into free space?
2. How can I add more space for `/`?

Comment: It's difficult to tell which is your root disk from the images shown (please don't post images when you don't have too!)  Can you add to your question the output of `df -h` ?  Additionally, running `sudo apt autoremove` may assist you, by removing old kernels.

Comment: Why do you have a 476G W95 partition? And why in the world do you have almost 20G of swap space? Also, please [edit] your question and add i) the output of `df -h` and the output of `lsblk`. Please don't post images of text. Instead, copy/paste the output directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @terdon `sda9 : /home` `sda7 : /` `sda8 : swap`

Comment: @MGJ please [edit] your question and add the information I asked for.

Comment: @terdon already edited the question!!

Comment: is this a dual boot system if not why so many partitions,and please tell what version of ubuntu you have.

Comment: @trond-hansen I have 3 different OS; Ubuntu 14.04(Localised Version), Linux Mint 18.3 and Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Boot your Machine from a Ubuntu-Live-CD.
2. Ubuntu-Software-Center: under "installed" click on gPartEd to show Details and uptop Button "Start" to launch. if its not there install gPartEd via: "All" Category click the Magnifying-Glass on top-right and type in gPartEd.
3. u should see the Layout of your Partitions for the active Disc (Disc can be changed via top-right DropDownList).
4. The Boundaries can be clicked and dragged to resize the Partitions, finalize by clicking the green Checkmark in upper Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

**gparted** can be used for these Tasks, its recommended to boot external from a Live-CD of course. https://gparted.org/

Comment: Please explain how to do that!